# VBA coding, lookup&match function

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
Sub lookup_macro()
  Dim X As Integer
  Dim erow As Integer
  Dim ecol As Integer

erow = Sheets("sheet1").Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
erow1 = Sheets("sheet2").Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ecol = Sheets("sheet2").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For X = 2 To erow1
  For Y = 2 To ecol

    Cells(X, Y) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("a" & X), Sheets("sheet1").Range("a1" & ":f", erow), _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(1, Y), Sheets("sheet1").Range("a1:f1"), 0), 0)
  Next Y
 
Next X

End Sub
```

I'm trying to combine `VLOOKUP()` with `MATCH()` function.
But it gives me an error with the *marked line. Could anyone help me solve this?

Comment: At the very least, `Range("a1" & ":f", erow)` is incorrectly written - you need something like `Range("a1:f" & erow)`

Comment: Put some dummy data and explain what you are trying to achieve.